# marquee stop onload

Tags: javascript, html, marquee

silly question, but I've tried with and without javascript, and I don't seem to be able to stop the marquees by default.

Basically I want them to start moving on mousover, but to be stopped by default.

I've tried stuff like this:

```
$.each($('.tracks_marquee'),function(){$(this).stop();}); //triggered on $.ready

<marquee class="tracks_marquee"
behavior="alternate"
scrolldelay="160"
onmouseover="this.start();"
onmouseout="this.stop();"
onload="this.stop();">
  some text here
</marquee>
```

but nothing works

Comment: try removing `$()` from `this`

Comment: Wow, `<marquee>`?? Old school! First two lines, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element

Comment: I know but with javascript plugins, the tags are getting replaced by divs and managed through js effects. It bugged me not to be ale to stop them like that though...

Comment: @Joseph with or without the $ it's the same thing, I'm using $(this) cause I'm using jquery

Comment: @Piero: If you are using some kind of javascript module to deal with the marquee then you should probably say which one it is. Also `this` is not the same as `$(this)`. The former is a dom element whereas the second is a jQuery object so will have different methods and properties on them.

Comment: @elclanrs but even with the jquery marquee plugin, I still cannot stop the marquee to start moving on page load...

Comment: @Chris there's only one jquery marquee plugin, and you're right for the this and $(this), but actually in this case none worked, I wasn't clear enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<marquee class="tracks_marquee" behavior="alternate" scrollamount="0"  >
  some text here
</marquee>



   $(document).ready(function()
{
$(".tracks_marquee").hover
  (
    function()
    {
       $(this).attr("scrollamount","1");
       $(this).start();  
    },
    function()
    {
       $(this).attr("scrollamount","0");
       $(this).stop();
    }
  )
})
```

Check this live in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/BM2Cq/