# Delay in catching mouseout event in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, gwt

I created a GWT marquee which works with a loop that moves the text a couple of pxs ahead every few mili-seconds. Did not use the  element because it's not compliant and frowned upon. Did not use CSS3/HTML5 because IE does not (yet) support it.

Now I also added a mouseListener to capture the mouseover and mouseOut events, so that when the mouse is over the marquee, the scrolling pauses.

Everything works perfectly in chrome, Firefox, safari etc. But NOT IE (Thank you, MSFT)!

When I move the mouse in, the marquee pauses as expected, but when I move the mouse out, sometimes (not consistently) - especially if I move the mouse really quickly, the marquee doesn't resume scrolling until half a second or a second later. It looks like it's taking IE that much time to realize the mouse has left the marquee and trigger an event.

There are quite a few posts on StackOverflow about IE not capturing the MouseOut event at all, but that's not the same as my experience. It seems like the event is always captured eventually, just with a 0.5~1.5 second delay many of the times.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be the problem?

Thank you!!!

Comment: As far as i know, IE7 and 8 supports a few (but not all) of CSS3 already. There is also a work-around (the "IE Shiv") to make HTML5 work on IE. And it may depend on the code running on the browser. Stuff like loops could hinder immediate reactions of these scripts (similar to choppy scrolling when there is an event bound to the scroll)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, IE does not support CSS scroller. (http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/css3-marquee.html), and we can't really go install stuff on a user's computer. :( thanks for the comment though.

Comment: similar question (although using the marquee tag and inverse to what you need) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376216/marquee-stop-onload/9377732#9377732